# Tensorflow Object Detection return label to an if statement

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

Based on the object_detection_tutorial jupyter notebook file.
As a test if a person is detected within an Image I am trying to upload that image to an S3 bucket but before i do that, i am testing the if statement by printing to screen.

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
    with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
        image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
        detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
        detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
        detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
        num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
        for i in TEST_IMAGE_PATHS:
            image = Image.open(i)
            image_np = load_image_into_numpy_array(image)
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
            vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(image_np,np.squeeze(boxes),
                                                         np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                                                         np.squeeze(scores),
                                                         category_index,
                                                         use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                                                         line_thickness=3)
            class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
            #if('name'.format(i) == 'person'):
            if(class_name == 'person'):
                    print('Test')
```

I am currently getting the following Error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:21: VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-259-372505bf7bda> in <module>()
     19                                                          use_normalized_coordinates=True,
     20                                                          line_thickness=3)
---> 21             class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
     22             #if('name'.format(i) == 'person'):
     23             if(class_name == 'person'):

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not on the printing part, it's how you retrieve the class name:

```
class_name = category_index[classes[i]]['name']
```

You should not be using `classes[i]`: `i` is the image index in your dataset; but in your batch you have only 1 image, so `classes[0]` contains info about the classes of the objects detected in the current image. Then, the class index for the `i_box`th box will be obtained by `classes[0][i_box]` (or `np.squeeze(classes)[i_box]` would work too).

So what you want is:

```
has_already_printed_sthg = False
for i_box in range(int(num[0])):  # To perform this for all detections. You can stop at a given number or depending on the threshold too.
    class_name = category_index[classes[0][i_box]]['name']
    #if('name'.format(i) == 'person'):
    if(class_name == 'person'):
        if not has_already_printed_sthg: # Print this only once
            print('Test')
            has_already_printed_sthg = True
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: It seems this goes through the category and prints out when it finds person, i am trying to print out person only if it was detected within an image.

Comment: No it does not, but you probably always have some detection with this label. You should probably replace `for i_box in range(int(num[0])):` (which looks at all detections, there are often 300 but it depends on your config file) with `while score[0][i_box]>thresh: `, with `i_box+=1` in the loop and `thresh=0.5` for instance. Then you'll only consider the detections that the neural network believes are quite good (estimated probability of being a true detection >50%)